# Looping through two different sized arrays while repeating array 1 values

Tags: javascript

Hi I an new to programming and am experiencing looping problems.
I have two arrays :

```
colour = ['red','blue','green','orange'];
rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...];
```

I want to have each row element pair with a colour from the colour array, for example starting

```
rows[0]=>colours[0],
rows[1]=>colours[1],
rows[2]=>colours[2],
rows[3]=>colours[3],
rows[4]=>colours[0],
rows[5]=>colours[1],.....
```

I basically want to start iterating over the colours once they runout

Comment: `rows.forEach(function (v, i) {
  rows[i] = colour[i%4];
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something along the lines of this:

```
var i,
    rowCount,
    colour,
    rows;
colour = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'];
rows = [];
rowCount = 20;
for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    rows[i] = colour[i % colour.length];
}
```

The key to this working is the modulus operator (remainder after division). `i % color.length` is the remainder of `i` divided by `color.length`, which relates to the indices of `colour`.

Comment: I had that exact same answer but saw yours as I was about to submit mine... kudos for the speedy answer.

Comment: You could probably use `i < rows.length` instead of `rowCount`.

Comment: @ArthurMigdal, I considered that, but as rows was being overwritten, it seemed more likely that the length was coming in as an external input.

Comment: Thanks a million, it worked like a charm. Everyday is a school day :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate thorugh all rows and assign colors in order. When the collor array is done just reset its index.

```
    var colorIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i)
     {
         row[i] = colours[j]; //use the color for the current row
         j++;
         if (j == colours.length) //when you reached the last colour 
          {
              j = 0; //reset colour index.
          }
    }
```